# dataGrid var= don't use a class name here

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Just spent a few hours chasing an unexplained loss of data.

```
<p:dataGrid value="#{search.compoundRecommendations}" var="triplet"
columns="1" layout="grid">
<h:form>
    <p:commandLink action="sense"
        actionListener="#{search.createSense}" ajax="false">
        <f:attribute name="lexemeID"
            value="#{triplet.lexeme.lexemeKey.key}" />
        <f:attribute name="headID"
            value="#{triplet.head.interlingualKey.key}" />
        <f:attribute name="modRelID"
            value="#{triplet.modRel.interlingualKey.key}" />
        <f:attribute name="modifierID"
            value="#{triplet.modifier.interlingualKey.key}" />
        <h:outputText value="#{triplet.defaultName}" />
    </p:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

The recommendations list is a list of class *Triplet*. For some reason the dataGrid instantiates the class Triplet() instead of assigning a list entry to the variable of name *triplet*. Renaming to var="t" fixed it.

Seems to be a bug, unless someone can explain why it should do it that way.

Comment: do you use the the name `triplet` in another field?

Comment: nope, I use the same approach in a different page and misspelled var="triple". Data showed up there, that's what baffled me. I "corrected" the variable name to "triplet" and data disappeared.

Comment: i already test it and it work fine with you, can you share your managed bean please?

Comment: isolating the code to post, so far, I cannot get it to fail.

Comment: It is not a bug unless you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem and has no explanation of why it should happen. And does it fail if you create a simple `h:dataTable` too? If it does it is jsf related and not PrimeFaces. (and it is not java-se related, you cannot reproduce with just a plain jdk)

Comment: In other words, you have a `@Named public class Triplet {}` somewhere?

Comment: agree, I tried build a minimal example and it does not reproduce. Only when I started to suck in the more complex objects referred to in recommendations was I able to reproduce. it has nothing to do with the name of the var, only if it is a class.  Will edit the original post with more info.

Comment: Yes, @named class Triplet.  Or as I know now, any other name. If the class name matches with the variable name, then the output text will disappear. There is a triplet instance in the list. In triplet.defaultName it uses the default instantiation of Triplet(), all triplet variable content is null. Prior, I can debug getCompoundRecomendations() and the list has values. Changing all to var="t" will fix the problem.

Comment: BalusC is right, I also expected this to be the case and hoped you'd find this in making an mcve. In your last comment some important thing is missing  _If the class name matches with the variable name,_ **and the class has a `@Named` (or `@ManagedBean`) annotation** This behaviour is not a bug but just the way it works.